# Crop Flash Webcam image

Tags: flash, webcam

I have a kiosk that takes peoples images using flash webcam video. We are using a 16:9 camera, but we need the images it takes to be 4:3. So I just made the stage 4:3 and added the video to it, and that solves it on the kiosk UI.

But... I am sending these images over to javascript via a base64 encoded jpg using ExternalInterface, and that works great. However, when I grab a video frame to send over, it is still the 16:9 of course.

So I need to crop the video so that when I grab it (or a display object it is added to), it is just the 4:3 image.

I tried using a mask, but it wouldn't take for some reason.

```
video = new Video(videoHeight, videoWidth); //backwards on purpose
video.x = -(videoWidth - stage.stageWidth) /2; //Center X
video.y = -(videoHeight - stage.stageHeight) /2; //Center Y


var maskSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
maskSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,640,480);

video.mask(maskSprite);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to use [Camera.setMode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode())?

Comment: How are you grabbing the video frame? Can you post that code?

Comment: @Art setMode is not set to the same aspect ratio seems to squish the video.

Comment: @ilollar `var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height);
bmd.draw(video);
   
imagePreview = new Bitmap(bmd);
this.addChild(imagePreview);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking `video` won't make a difference, since the `draw` method of `BitmapData` is drawing from `video` itself (which won't include masking) If you put `video` and the mask into another `Sprite` and used `draw` on that `Sprite`, then the mask would work.

The best solution, however, is probably to adjust the rectangle of what the `BitmapData` is drawing. You'll also probably want to adjust the width and height of the `BitmapData` as well:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 480);
bmd.draw(video, null, null, null, new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480));
```

Basically, you're defining a rectangle for the `clipRect` parameter, and setting the size of that rectangle to the final size (and aspect ratio) of what you're trying to capture.